# JavaScript library to work with numbers higher than 2^53 as strings

Tags: javascript

Since javascript supports numbers up to 2^53, this will be a problem for the algorithm I'm making. Therefore, I'm looking for solutions in terms of working with very high numbers converted as strings. On my search, I found [this solution](http://www.2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html) which ended up being a problem because it was literally not working. 
Anyway, that's the point, I'm searching for some libraries that I could work in a way like `add("123","123")` > 246 or `multiply("2","3")` > 6. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/ https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/